# Will I lose purchased items if I reset my tower?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I am in a strange place in the game now.  I have -399 bux due to what I can only hope is a bug, but the motivation to play is gone because of it.  I want to reset, but I had paid to upgrade the elevator and get some bux when the game first launched.  If I reset the game to fix the big negative balance, will I have literally lost that money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I had to try this tonight.  I couldn't live with -399 bux ($15 just to get back to 0).  So I reset.  You lose EVERYTHING.  Doesn't matter if you paid for the elevator upgrade.

And yes I agree it is a free game and I have a great time playing when I have a few free minutes.  But when you hit an in game bug that causes you to go negative balance it is quite frustrating.

This makes me seriously question playing on a Windows Phone.  If your phone is wiped and you reinstall the app doesn't have your data and will start over again at zero.  So if you play for 6 months and then upgrade your phone...  start over, no thanks.

Same on the Windows 8 version of Tiny Death Star.  On my tablet and laptop I have two different Death Stars (dumb).  It is EASY to add a settings sync to the app so all versions of the app have the same data, the fact that they didn't do this makes me seriously question spending time in this game.

At least the iPhone version keeps a backup of your data in iCloud so you don't lose all the time you spent on the game.

Comment: It is a game that if you are patient, doesn't require a penny. As a free game, I enjoy it.

Comment: Syncing is **NOT** *easy*. It is a lot of work and there are many things you have to keep in mind. It might *look* easy to do, but it really isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I am a dev on Windows Platform - syncing on Windows is EASY.  You store the data file in a folder, and Windows takes care of it for you.  Now it won't work across phone and Windows 8, only Win8 devices, but it works really well and is so simple to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you reset the game, you will lose everything you bought.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can restore in-app purchases.

Nimblebit's policy seems to be that you can manually restore tower bux and other purchases via their [support page](http://support.nimblebit.com/customer/portal/articles/824776-restore-in-app-purchase). When you reset the game, contact them and have your bux restored.

Comment: "Consumable purchases cannot be restored automatically, these items include"  Tiny Tower Bux - so they won't restore bux.

Comment: The keyword here is automatically. You should contact support.